# Progress bar with APC and Codeigniter - Trouble with IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, upload, progress-bar, apc

I am trying to make a progress bar with Codeigniter and APC.

Here's my form :

```
<form method="post" action="" id="upload_file" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="result_frame">

<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo uniqid(); ?>" id="progress_key" name="APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS" />

<p><label for="userfile">S&eacute;l&eacute;ctionnez un fichier</label><br />
<input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" size="20" />
&nbsp;
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"><span class="icon-upload"></span>&nbsp;Valider</button></p>
```

When the user hits the submit button, it fires the upload process. Here is my "check-progress" function :

```
function checkProgress() {

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/fbe_upload/index.php/fbeupload/upload_progress",
    async: true,
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        session_unid: $('#progress_key').val()
    },
    //Success
    success: function(data) {

        //Progress
        liveProgress = data.progress;

        //Progress bar
        $('#progressBar-' + idRow).attr("class", "progress progress-striped active");
        $('#progressBar-' + idRow + " div.bar").css("width", parseInt(liveProgress) + "%");
        $('#td-pc-' + idRow).html(parseInt(liveProgress) + "% t&eacute;l&eacute;charg&eacute;s");

        //END success    
    },
    //Error
    error: function() {
        //Erreur
        alert("Error.");
    }
    //Ajax END   
});

//Progress < 100
if (liveProgress < 100) {
    //Call function again
    setTimeout(checkProgress, 800);
}
//Else
else if (liveProgress === 100) {

    //Progress bar
    $('#progressBar-' + idRow).attr("class", "progress progress-striped active");
    $('#progressBar-' + idRow + " div.bar").css("width", "100%");
    $('#td-pc-' + idRow).html("100% t&eacute;l&eacute;charg&eacute;s");

    //Message
    $('#td-filename-' + idRow).html("<i>Finalisation en cours...</i>");

    //This function manage the end of the upload process (message, buttons,...)
    setTimeout(endUpload, 4800);

    //Else END   
}

else {
    setTimeout(checkProgress, 1200);
}
//checkProgress END
}
```

And here is my PHP file :

```
function upload_progress() {

//Key
$key = 'upload_' . $_POST['session_unid'];

$status = apc_fetch($key);
//Progress
$cal = ceil($status['current'] / $status['total'] * 100);

echo json_encode(array('progress' => $cal));

}
```

So, when the user clicks on "submit", his file is uploaded (I used **[this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-upload-files-with-codeigniter-and-ajax/)** to write my upload function) and the function checkProgress is called after 1.5 s.

With Firefox, everything works fine. I've got the right values and the progress bar behaves like I want. With IE and Chrome, it doesn't work properly : for the "Progress" value, IE always returns 420 and Chrome 410. So, it is like the upload process is already finished but it's not. By the way, these values ​​do not correspond to the size of the file, or something else. I don't understand how it is possible that Firefox computes and returns the right value and not the other browsers.

### WITH FIREFOX :

```
Array
(
    [total] => 791309142
    [current] => 113631842
    [filename] => up.rar
    [name] => userfile
    [done] => 0
    [start_time] => 1370864635.9486
)
```

### WITH CHROME :

```
Array
(
    [total] => 410
    [current] => 410
    [rate] => 22777015.099338
    [filename] => 
    [name] => userfile
    [cancel_upload] => 4
    [done] => 1
    [start_time] => 1370864408.3726
)
```

In my php.ini I have this :

```
extension=php_apc.dll

[APC]
apc.enabled = 1
apc.max_file_size = 5000M
apc.rfc1867 = On
apc.mmap_file_mask = C:\wamp\tmp\file_template_%s.tmp
apc.shm_segments = 1
apc.shm_size = 64M
apc.stat=1
```

Does anybody have a suggestion? It will be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that the correct session_unid is being sent in chrome and ie?  If it is, is it possible the request is getting cached? Try appending a timestamp to the request and see if you get a different result.  Can't help more without more info / some kind of fiddle

Comment: @LancelotKiin Did you ever find your answer? If not, I'll take a stab at helping you.

Comment: try to add at `$.ajax` param `cache : false`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a IE cache issue

try to flag `$.ajax` request parameters with `cache` set a `false` or/and add a timestamp to request

```
function checkProgress() {

    $.ajax({
        type  : "POST",
        url   : "/fbe_upload/index.php/fbeupload/upload_progress?t=" + (new Date().getTime()),
        cache : false,
    // ....
```

and add no-cache headers for `/fbe_upload/index.php/fbeupload/upload_progress` route

```
header('Expires: Tue, 08 Oct 1991 00:00:00 GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
```